# Mysql repeatable read-your-own-write behavior

Tags: mysql

If my isolation level is repeatable read, and I have a **transaction** with 3 statements:

- `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 1;`       (Read the row)
- `UPDATE table1 SET ... WHERE id = 1;`     (Modify the row)
- `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 1;`       (Read the row again)

Will the last select statement see the change made by the second statement?

Comment: Yes, why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: Thanks, do you know what part of the mysql documentation that refers to this behavior?

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to find this, but the sequence is exactly how it's done. You read to check data, edit it and then just check again. If your UPDATE is valid, the select shall return the new values.

Comment: Why would the last select need to be part of your transaction. Commit after the Insert (free all the locks) and let everybody see your changes

Comment: Here is a link to the [MYSQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html) Specifically _All consistent reads within the same transaction read the snapshot established by the first read. This convention means that if you issue several plain (nonlocking) SELECT statements within the same transaction, these SELECT statements are consistent also with respect to each other._

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course! All transactions always see its own changes, no matter which isolation level they have.